# Best approach for designing Rails app with two separate parts for members and non-members

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am designing a Rails application that should have a simple landing page for non members and more complex dashboard style section for members.

Here I am facing two problems:

1. Should I use subdomains (http://members.mydomain.com) or namespaces: (http://mydomain.com/members)? What's are pros and cons for each approach? Any other options?
2. How should I separate assets for each section? the styles are very different - public section is simple bootstrap theme but member's area is complex javascript-heavy application and I prefer not to mix the assets together.

The question might sound subjective (at least SO engine complains about that) but I am not experienced in rails and trying each approach by myself will waste lot of effort, so I decided to ask more experienced members about their opinions

Comment: for first point, I'd say the decision is subjective. Vanity urls(subdomain) are nice way to tell your users that they own a domain(virtually of course) on your site and easy to remember, the downside is you can never mount any subdomain for other purpose in future, while in namespaces, users think they own an account, no downsides as such. 
For Second point: You can put your javascripts in different directories(public & members) and compile their `index.js` file explicitly. So, you won't have any overhead of maintaining and separating them in your code.

Comment: @Surya - Thanks for your comment. as for subdomains my intention was not one subdomain per user but single "members" subdomain to serve as separate site for logged in members.So for example url for user profile would be members.mydomain.com/profile/123 or mydomain.com/members/profile/123 for a user with ID=123.  As for usage of index.js file - I didn't know that option, thanks. I will try to find more info on that matter

Comment: Aah, now I see. I don't think you need a subdomain then. You can manage your js files by separate them by locating them in different directories. If you can post the js files you want to separate then I can probably try to give you a logical separation if you are not sure how to do it. Also, you don't have to have this: **mydomain.com/members/profile/123** you can just do: **mydomain.com/members/profile** and find the user with `current_user` helper. it's actually much cleaner.